# Problem with SDL2_image.dll and libpng16-16.dll

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019, sdl-2, sdl-image

Problem with SDL2_image.dll and libpng16-16.dll

When calling IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);    I get a "failed" return.
IMG_GetError() returns "Failed loading libpng16-16.dll"

When checking output in debug mode both dlls are loaded and immediately unloaded.
Other SDL2 functions works as expected.
Both dlls are placed in the same folder as the .exe
I suspect one or both dlls are bad.  I can find them at several places on the net but
at no place I trust right away.
Can anybody recommend at trustworthy site for these dlls ?
Or any advice on what my problem might be ?

Comment: You don't trust binaries from libsdl.org, perhaps you don't trust to build it yourself from github repo ... what we can do? Why you trust us then?

Answer (score 0):

After again downloading SDL2_image-2.0.5-win32-x64 from [www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)  and coping ALL the dlls found there into my project I am able execute IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG); with an ok return.  Go figure....
May I suggest that a link to [www.libsdl.org/projects/](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/) is placed on the index page, or better, a nice menu with the SDL project found there